# Entity Framework Core verify SaveChanges count

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and have been assigned a task to verify the count of changes done using `SaveChanges()`.
It is expected that the **developer should know how many records will be changed before-hand** when `SaveChanges()` will be called.

To implement it, I have created an extension method for `DbContext` called `SaveChangesAndVerify(int expectedChangeCount)` where I am using transaction and equating this parameter with the return value of `SaveChanges()`.
If the values match, the transaction is committed and if it doesn't match, the transaction is rolled back.

Please check the code below and let me know if it would work and if there are any considerations that I need to make. Also, is there a **better way to do this**?

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static int SaveChangesAndVerify(this DbContext context, int expectedChangeCount)
    {
        context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        var actualChangeCount = context.SaveChanges();
        if (actualChangeCount == expectedChangeCount)
        {
            context.Database.CommitTransaction();
            return actualChangeCount;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Database.RollbackTransaction();
            throw new DbUpdateException($"Expected count {expectedChangeCount} did not match actual count {actualChangeCount} while saving the changes.");
        }
    }

    public static async Task<int> SaveChangesAndVerifyAsync(this DbContext context, int expectedChangeCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        var actualChangeCount = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if(actualChangeCount == expectedChangeCount)
        {
            context.Database.CommitTransaction();
            return actualChangeCount;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Database.RollbackTransaction();
            throw new DbUpdateException($"Expected count {expectedChangeCount} did not match actual count {actualChangeCount} while saving the changes.");
        }
    }
}
```

A sample usage would be like `context.SaveChangesAndVerify(1)` where a developer is expecting only 1 record to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of another way of doing this - only the database knows how many rows have been affected. That said, your code has some problems.

You need to dispose of your transaction when you're done with it. This has 2 additional benefits:

1. You don't need to rollback manually
2. You don't need to worry about exceptions in SaveChanges (you haven't handled that at all at the moment).

Let's look at how that changes things:

```
public static int SaveChangesAndVerify(
    this DbContext context,
    int expectedChangeCount)
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var actualChangeCount = context.SaveChanges();
        if (actualChangeCount == expectedChangeCount)
        {
            transaction.Commit();
            return actualChangeCount;
        }
        throw new DbUpdateException($"Expected count {expectedChangeCount} did not match actual count {actualChangeCount} while saving the changes.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reviewing the code.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do this at all.

For one, Entity Framework keeps track of expected changes itself, probably better than you can do it.

> It is expected that the developer should know how many records will be changed before-hand

How? Only in the utter most simple scenarios they will be able to do that. The power of EF is that you can save entire object graphs. Good luck trying to figure out how many records are going too be affected. Keep in mind that even when entities are modified in your code that doesn't always mean they are actually *changed* from EF's perspective. Or some changes may not even visible to you (think of many-to-many associations, or foreign keys set to `null` when associations are severed). In short: this is pointless, and not necessary at all.

EF knows how many rows are expected to be changed by a `SaveChanges()` call. If there is a difference it will throw a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exception and roll back the transaction. For example when a record is deleted while it's not present in the database anymore:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

As you see, EF assumes that exceptions like this are caused by concurrency, but you can easily raise one by committing an entity with a non-existing primary key value.

Which means, secondly, that you don't need to start and commit a transaction yourself. `SavaChanges` manages its own transaction and won't commit anything if there's an exception.

As a matter of fact, the line `throw new DbUpdateException` should never be hit: if there is a difference, `SaveChanges()` will already have thrown and if the line *is* reached you probably made a mistake in determining `expectedChangeCount`.

The end conclusion is that you can, no *should*, remove these methods altogether. Simply call `SaveChanges(Async)` where you need it and handle exceptions as usual.